# Direct product vs Cartesian product

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-product

Are the above two terms synonyms? Because for example [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirectProduct.html) they seem to explain it like so. But then I don't get the following part:

> Direct products satisfy the property that, given maps $\alpha:S \to A$ and $\beta:S \to B$, there exists a unique map $S \to A×B$ given by $(\alpha(s),\beta(s))$.

Can anyone explain what is meant by this?

Comment: The way it’s explained on the page you linked, a direct product of groups, for example, is a group where the underlying set is the Cartesian product of the underlying sets

Comment: The point is that the direct product imposes an algebraic structure on the Cartesian product of the underlying sets that preserves in an obvious way their algebraic structure.  So they're not quite synonymous, but they're closely related.  To see why this is a non-trivial distinction, review the various different topologies that can be imposed on an arbitrary Cartesian product of topological spaces.

Comment: @Robert Shore - I would assume it is correct to say that one obtains a Cartesian product from the direct product via a forgetful functor (e.g. from groups to the underlying sets).

Comment: @geguze That sounds correct, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with the vocabulary of functors to make that statement with confidence.

Comment: @geguze You have it reversed: the Cartesian Product is a special type of limit in the category of Sets. It satisfies the universal property in the boldface of your post (which is really the definition of a special type of categorical limit). Now in the category of groups, the morphisms are group $homomorphisms$, and the direct product is defined as the limit i.e. the object --the group--that satisfies the required UMP. Of course you need to check that the direct product as defined does satisfy the UMP. I do not see how the forgetful functor: Grp$\to $Set enters into this analysis.

Comment: Can anyone explain the quoted part of my question?